# Multiple CALayer borders on UIImage

Tags: swift, calayer

I am trying to add two different border layers to my image.

I have added the first with the following code:

`myImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        myImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        myImage.roundLayerCorners()`

When I do something like:

`let sublayer: CALayer = CALayer()
   sublayer.backgroundCOlor = UIColor.white.cgColor
   sublayer.borderWith = 4.0
   myImage.layer.addSublayer(sublayer)`

It doesn't show up at all. Why, and how would I add multiple borders?

I want a 2 pixel wide blue border followed by a 2 pixel wide white border

Thank you!

Comment: Hi there- it's not clear from your question but have you assigned your sublayer a frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sublayer does not have a frame. This means it does not know how big to make itself. You can solve this by adding one line of code:

```
sublayer.frame = CGRect(x:2, y: 2, width: myImage.frame.width - 4, height: myImage.frame.height - 4)
```

So that your setup of your sublayer would look like this:

```
let sublayer: CALayer = CALayer()
sublayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
sublayer.borderWidth = 4.0
sublayer.frame = CGRect(x:2, y: 2, width: myImage.frame.width - 4, height: myImage.frame.height - 4)
myImage.layer.addSublayer(sublayer)
```